# Chrome browsers stay open while running "fake parallelism" with TestCafe

Tags: parallel-processing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I'm currently using TestCafe as my main test framework in my company. I just encountered a problem recently: we have a designed pipeline that launches tests in a parallel way, but not the way Testcafe is supposed to work.

I know that testcafe can handle parallelism though concurrent test execution this way :

testcafe -c 3 chrome tests/test.js

However, our pipeline plays each testcafe test in its own browser without using the concurrent test execution procedure. The result is that, at the end of the execution, we have A LOT of chrome browsers still open in the task manager. I don't know how to handle this problem... I already tried to insert some code about window.close() at the "aftereach" of my fixtures but this is not working ...

I have to mention that, executing one test at a time doesn't produce this effect and all chrome browsers are closed correctly.

Thanks for your help!

Sylvain

This is the code that is executed :

```
execution {

    String nodejsPath = pathfileOfTestDirectory("nodejs/")
    String nodejsModulePath = nodejsPath + "/lib/node_modules"
    String npmPath = pathfileOfTestDirectory("nodejs/npm.cmd")

    new File(resultDir).mkdirs();
    logcatoutput resultDir + "logcat.log"
    inDirectory pathfileOfTestDirectory("tests-e2e")
    within 60, TimeUnit.MINUTES

    env "Path", readEnv("Path") + ";" + nodejsPath
    env "NODE_PATH", nodejsModulePath

    String browserPath;

    switch(browser) {
        case "firefox":
            //browserPath = pathfileOfTestDirectory("/resources/browsers/firefox/firefox.exe")
            browserPath = pathfileOfTestDirectory("/resources/browsers/chrome/Application/chrome.exe")
            break
        case "chrome" :
            browserPath = pathfileOfTestDirectory("/resources/browsers/chrome/Application/chrome.exe")
            break
    }


    command npmPath, "run",
            "testcafe",
            "--scripts-prepend-node-path",// ensure the nodejs installation of the workspace is used
            "--",
            "path:`${browserPath}`",
            "testcafe/",
            "--targetEnv=" + targetEnv,
            "--targetPage=" + targetPage,
            "--test=\"${testName}\"", "-q",
            "-r", "json:${resultDir}result.json",
            "-s", "${resultDir}"

    logger.info("Execution done")


}
```

Comment: Could you please share the code of your pipeline system?

Comment: Just added the code ;)

Comment: Could you try to specify browsers as `"chrome:`${browserPath}`"` and `"firefox:{$browserPath}"`? TestCafe has a special way to terminate Chrome and Firefox browsers but it is enabled only when you use `chrome` and `firefox` browser providers explicitly.

Comment: ok i will try that !